# Scaning barcode with web cam into input field

Tags: javascript, barcode, barcode-scanner

I want to implement barcode scaning into my web app and I want to use the web cam as scanner. So there is a field and a button. After clicking the button scanner opens and after successful scan the barcode is written in the input field. I searched and I couldn't find good tutorial how to do that. I tried using QuaggaJS barcode scanner written in JavaScript but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried ZBar or zbarimg? It's built off the ImageMagick library.

Comment: What issue did you run into with QuaggaJS? It decodes 1D bar codes. If you need to support QR Code or other 2D code, you may try [this one](https://github.com/dynamsoft-dbr/javascript-barcode)